# mongodb import filename as additional field?

Tags: mongodb, csv, data-import

I have a large number of csv files i'd like to load into MongoDB - what i'd like to do (for testing and data lineage) is load in the filename that the records came from as an additional field within the document - i've looked at the mongoimport syntax, but it doesn't appear possible to do it there.

What i'd like is from a csv (i.e. users1.csv) file containing
USERID,NAME,EMAIL
1,John, john@example.com

Which would be loaded into a collection with
_ID,USERID,NAME,EMAIL,SOURCEFILE
XXXXXX,1,John, john@example.com,users1.csv

What ways of achieving this are there that anyone can recommend?

1 - I've thought about running some pre process to create the sourcename within the file, but ideally I don't want to change the original datasource.

2 - I've thought about updating the dataset with the filename retrospectively - this seems like a good option, but needs to happen between loading sets (e.g. after users1.csv is imported and before users2.csv gets imported).

Does anyone have any suggestions as to an elegant way of doing this? Would appreciate anyones input.

Comment: what problems did you face with mongoimport ? did you try it ?

Comment: I did do mongoimport, didn't get any errors, but couldn't see an option within the syntax to use the current filename as a field...

Comment: mongoimport can't add in the file name for you. You should do 1, 2, or use a csv library and a driver to write an import job yourself.

Answer (score -2):

Im not sure why you cant use mongo import ?

```
mongoimport -d databaseToUse -c Collection --type csv --ignoreBlanks --file users1.csv --headerline
```

--headerline uses the first line as field names this should import the file no problem..

You can specify the fields later if you like with

```
--fields <field1[,field2]>, -f <field1[,field2] etc etc>
```

I have tested this out and had no issues..

As for adding to it, you could use an updateOne function in conjunction to add the filename to the record..

```
var bulk = dataBaseToUse.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({name:someField}).update( { $set: { sourceFile: fileName } } );
```

Something along those lines maybe ?

From the initial import you can add the details in 1 go using the `-f` param for fields..

Something like this will create the field

```
mongoimport -d databaseToUse -c Collection --type csv --ignoreBlanks --file users1.csv -f "id, userID, name, email, sourceFile"
```

from there then you will need to update the entire collection in another 1 liner.

The import is just that.. and import tool only. Not an import and edit on the fly.

The update function would be something along these lines :

```
dataBaseToUse.Collection.update(
  {
     $set: { sourceFile: "users1.csv" }
  })
```

i will need to test these 100% to make sure but it can work! :)

Comment: I was able to import the data without any problems, but couldn't think of a way of automating the process for a batch of files and adding the additional filename field too - will doing --fields <sourceFile['users1.csv'] allow me to append additional fields to the headerline?

Comment: @mr_gooding I have updated the answer now there seem to be 2 steps i can see. There is a `$setOnInsert` available but i cant seem to apply it on the mongoimport method! :(

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like the way to do it - then I could call a wrapper script which called the mongoimport then mongo.exe with the 2nd update command to set the sourcefile. appreciate your help on this - will let you know when i've had a chance to try this tomorrow.

Comment: is it possible to add "key":"value" pair as an additional filed which is not there in importing file?